# How can I run the timer function in python bottle?

Tags: python, bottle

I'd like to print 't' and  's' on localhost. But it doesn't work with timer function. Here is what I tried.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time
from bottle import route, run

def timer(n):
    while True:
        url2 = 'https://api.bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=USDT-BTC'
        res = requests.get(url2).json()
        BTC = pd.json_normalize(res['result'])
        t = time.ctime()
        s = BTC.to_html(index=False)
        time.sleep(n)
timer(5)

@route('/')
def index():
    return t, s
run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

Comment: def timer(n) <-- inside this make global t and global s

Comment: Can you be more specific than "it doesn't work"?

Answer (score 0):

Without more details around what exactly isn't working, it's tough to give a comprehensive answer. But one thing that surely needs to change is where you define `t` and `s`. As @Pygirl states in her comment, you'll need to define those globally:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time
from bottle import route, run

t = ''
s = ''

def timer(n):
    while True:
        url2 = 'https://api.bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=USDT-BTC'
        res = requests.get(url2).json()
        BTC = pd.json_normalize(res['result'])

        # Must declare t and s as globals since you're changing their referents.
        global t
        global s
        t = time.ctime()
        s = BTC.to_html(index=False)

        time.sleep(n)

timer(5)

@route('/')
def index():
    return '{}: {}'.format(t, s)
run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

An alternative to defining them globally is to create a top-level dict with two items in it (`t` and `s`), and simply modify those items as needed; no need for `global` in that case.